# Use an existing Content Type when you create a new list with PnP-js in SharePoint Framework?

Tags: list, content-type, spfx, sharepoint-framework, pnp

I've searched for hours to find an answer, but wasn't able to find anything I could use for my case.

I'm using PnP to create a new list on my site but I would like to use an already existing Content Type to create the list from. Is it even possible?

This is how I create the list:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share some code snippet showing us how you are creating a list ? You can also post a documentation link if it you are referring to it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added a code snippet to the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it after you've created the list.

First you need to have the CT ID

```
pnp.sp.site.rootWeb.contentTypes.select("StringId,Name").get()
 .then((cts: any) => {
   cts.forEach(ct => {
     if (ct.Name === ctName) {
       return resolve(ct.StringId);
     }
   });

   // no matching CTs found, don't add anything
   resolve("");
 })
```

So basically something like

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.add(listName, "", baseTemplate, true) // true here to allow CTs
    .then((lar: ListAddResult) => {
        lar.list.contentTypes.addAvailableContentType(ctId)
    });
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Please remember to mark question as answered.